# Filling in incomplete columns based on a column in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation, missing-data

[image]
I have data like this, where row 84 and 79 contains missing values.

I would like it to say Matanuska-Susitna in second column, Alaska in third column, and US in forth column.

Here is some reproducible data.

I tried using the editdata addin on R to change in manually, and separate function in tidyverse but I keep getting errors.

Thanks!

```
structure(list(FIPS = c(2122, 2130, 2150, 2158, 2164, 2170), 
    County = c("Kenai Peninsula -Alaska -US", "Ketchikan Gateway", 
    "Kodiak Island", "Kusilvak", "Lake and Peninsula", "Matanuska-Susitna -Alaska -US"
    ), State = c(NA, "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", 
    NA), Country = c(NA, "US", "US", "US", "US", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these options (`base R` and `fill()` from `tidyr`):

```
#Code 1
df$State[is.na(df$State)]<-'Alaska'
df$Country[is.na(df$Country)]<-'US'
#Code 2
df <- df %>% tidyr::fill(c(State,Country),.direction = 'downup')
```

The output in both cases will be:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   FIPS County                        State  Country
  <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>  <chr>  
1  2122 Kenai Peninsula -Alaska -US   Alaska US     
2  2130 Ketchikan Gateway             Alaska US     
3  2150 Kodiak Island                 Alaska US     
4  2158 Kusilvak                      Alaska US     
5  2164 Lake and Peninsula            Alaska US     
6  2170 Matanuska-Susitna -Alaska -US Alaska US
```

Comment: Thanks, the data actually has different states and countries so the first solution won't work. The second solution works 90% of the time until there is a one off state, so it fills in the wrong state but I can work with that. Thanks!